# I want to create a infographics Chart in Slider on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, graph-visualization, wpbakery

I want to create an infographics chart on my homepage something similar to like that
[https://step1.medbullets.com/[![1]]](https://step1.medbullets.com/%5B!%5B1%5D%5D)

It would be great if you could visit the website and try to open it for proper visualization